# IPP Printing returns Unauthorized

Tags: printing, laravel-5.6, cups, php-7.2

I want to print labels from my web application and to do that I am using this packages. (https://github.com/smalot/cups-ipp). Im using the example code provided by the package and when I send PDF file to print Im getting the following error:

Http\Client\Common\Exception\ClientErrorException(401)
Unauthorized

When I look at my printers queue I see the status is aborted and the size of the file is 0KB. I am sure the file is found the right way because when I do some debugging I can see that the stream of the PDF is coming in right but in the request that is send I can't found it back. The request is as followed:

```
Request {#995 ▼
  -method: "POST"
  -requestTarget: null
  -uri: Uri {#996 ▼
    -scheme: ""
    -userInfo: ""
    -host: ""
    -port: null
    -path: "/"
    -query: ""
    -fragment: ""
  }
  -headers: array:1 [▼
    "Content-Type" => array:1 [▼
      0 => "application/ipp"
    ]
  ]
  -headerNames: array:1 [▼
    "content-type" => "Content-Type"
  ]
  -protocol: "1.1"
  -stream: Stream {#998 ▼
    -stream: stream resource @14 ▼
      wrapper_type: "PHP"
      stream_type: "TEMP"
      mode: "w+b"
      unread_bytes: 0
      seekable: true
      uri: "php://temp"
      options: []
    }
    -size: 140
    -seekable: true
    -readable: true
    -writable: true
    -uri: "php://temp"
    -customMetadata: []
  }
}
```

I don't know if its valuable but my application is build on laravel 5.6.

The code for executing the print job:

```
public function testPrinter() {
    $client = new Client();
    $builder = new Builder();
    $responseParser = new ResponseParser();

    $printerManager = new PrinterManager($builder, $client, $responseParser);
    $printer = $printerManager->findByUri('ipp://localhost:631/printers/OKI_ES7131_D66B77');

    $jobManager = new JobManager($builder, $client, $responseParser);

    $job = new Job();
    $job->setName('job create file');
    $job->setUsername('kasper');
    $job->setCopies(1);
    $job->setPageRanges('1');
    $job->addFile('/var/www/justproduce/public/helloworld.pdf', 'test');
    $job->addAttribute('media', 'A4');
    $job->addAttribute('fit-to-page', true);
    $result = $jobManager->send($printer, $job);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had to initialize a new client with credentials. Works now.

Answer (score 1):

In my case (docker installation on a Synology NAS) it still needed username and password.

```
 $client = new Client('User', 'password');
```